# PSTricks with Geogebra

Tags: pstricks

This is the code generated by Geogebra, and when I try to compile the code with TeXmaker, using LaTeX, I get a pdf with a small picture.  Please, understand that I don't have any knowledge of PSTricks, and I just want to be able to put the pictures I make with Geogebra into LaTeX.

The intent was to draw a quadrangle.

Please, help me fix this code.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \newrgbcolor{ffqqtt}{1 0 0.2}
    \psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
    \begin{pspicture*}(-5.89,-1.06)(7.25,5.78)
        \psline[linecolor=ffqqtt](2.04,0.22)(0.75,3.33)
        \psline[linecolor=ffqqtt](-3.26,0.3)(2.69,2.23)
        \psline[linecolor=ffqqtt](0.75,3.33)(2.69,2.23)
        \psline(2.69,2.23)(6.32,0.16)
        \psline[linecolor=ffqqtt](0.75,3.33)(-3.26,0.3)
        \psline[linecolor=ffqqtt](-3.26,0.3)(2.04,0.22)
        \psline[linecolor=ffqqtt](2.04,0.22)(2.69,2.23)
        \psline(3.8,5.64)(0.75,3.33)
        \psline(3.8,5.64)(2.69,2.23)
        \psline(2.04,0.22)(6.32,0.16)
        \begin{scriptsize}
            \psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=blue](3.8,5.64)
            \rput[bl](3.87,5.57){\blue{$D$}}
            \psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=red](-3.26,0.3)
            \rput[bl](-3.56,0.5){\red{$A$}}
            \psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=blue](6.32,0.16)
            \rput[bl](6.19,-0.16){\blue{$B$}}
            \psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=red](0.75,3.33)
            \rput[bl](0.54,3.44){\red{$C$}}
            \psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=red](2.04,0.22)
            \rput[bl](1.94,-0.21){\red{$E$}}
            \psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=red](2.69,2.23)
            \rput[bl](3.13,2.21){\red{$F$}}
        \end{scriptsize}
    \end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: 1493 characters are used.

Comment: @TheLastError I don't understand 1493 characters used?

Answer (score 6):

Without using Geogebra that generates  inefficient PSTricks code.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=25pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset{PointSymbol=none,linejoin=2}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(8,5)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,0,135,45,-90}]{A}(8,0){B}(3,3){C}([nodesep=6]{C}A){D}([nodesep=5]{B}A){E}
    \pstInterLL[PosAngle=45]{E}{D}{C}{B}{F}
    \psline(C)(D)(F)(B)(E)\psline[linecolor=red](A)(E)(F)(C)(A)(F)(E)(C)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 403 characters are used.

Comment: It is hard for me to think of the projections I need for class, without having something to draw them with, as I would like to be able to just code the answers, I am not that smart.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it won't be big enough to suit your needs, but if you remove the lines

```
\begin{scriptsize}
```

and

```
\end{scriptsize}
```

you will obtain bigger letters. Either way, it compiles here without problems and indeed I obtain a normal-sized quadrangle.

[image]

Comment: What I get is as if everything was stacked upon itself in one small 1mm X 1mm cube.  I am using texmaker. I click the latex option to build and then click view pdf.

Comment: It works fine here with texmaker too. What happens if you try to compile and view by the quickest way (press F1)?

Answer (score 1):

run that document with `xelatex` or configure TeXmaker to use the sequence`latex->dvips->ps2pdf` when you use `quickbuild`, which can be set via
 Options->Configure TeXmaker->Quick Build`. In the right menu choose the latex/dvips/ps2pdf sequence